# There are at least one continuous fractal from dimension 0 to 1?

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

(I do not speak English. Please, excuse my bad grammar.)

This is about fractals over the real line, composed of points or segments inside the real line.

If the integers set is a fractal with dimension D=0, and the real line is a fractal with dimension D=1, then is possible to continuously vary the dimension D from the integer set to the real line set? (making some continuous figure in the plane)

There is a drawing of all the fractals side by side? (something like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tlutc.png))

I do not mean that all the fractals make one larger fractal, but just that for each value D there is one fractal over the real line with that dimension, and all the fractals "touch each neighbor" continuously.

In other words, I want to continuously transform a fractal, from the integer set to the real line, by continuously changing his dimension D from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by generalizing the Cantor set. In particular, fix some $\alpha$ to be the dimension and let $\beta=2^{-1/\alpha}$. Define two functions $f_1(x)=\beta x$ and $f_2(x)=1-\beta+\beta x$, which are contractions towards $0$ and $1$ respectively. One may prove that there is a unique compact set $S_{\alpha}$ such that $S=f_1(S_{\alpha})\cup f_2(S_{\alpha})$. We have that $S_{1/
\log_2(3)}$ is the Cantor set and $S_1=[0,1]$ and in the limit as $\alpha$ goes to $0$, we get the set $\{0,1\}$. Additionally, it is fairly clear that $S_{\alpha}$ has dimension $\alpha$, since, being composed of two copies of it scaled by $\beta$, its dimension satisfies $\beta^{d}=1/2$.

One may prove that $S_{\alpha}$ consists exactly of points $x$ of the form, where $s_i$ is a sequence in $\{0,1\}$:
$$x=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}s_i(1-\beta)\beta^i$$
which clearly varies continuously when $s_i$ is fixed. A plot of these fractals follows, where the cross-section of the graph at $x=d$ is a fractal of dimension $d$:
[image]

Comment: Of course, if you actually want to continuously move from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb R$, you can just union together the translates of $S_{\alpha}$ by every integer. That's harder to plot.

Comment: Thanks Milo. I didn't knew that the cantor set could be modified to have any dimension.

Comment: Thanks Milo, and thanks for making the graphic!

You are right. I'm looking for a grasp of what are natural sets between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, and I'm still lost... :(

I imagine that there are many ways to "interpolate" between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ with fractals. I don't even know where to look.