# There is a natural set of numbers with dimension in [0,1]?

Tags: fractals, continuous-geometry

After reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074339/there-are-at-least-one-continuous-fractal-from-dimension-0-to-1), I want to know: if $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{R}^0$ (according to Hausdorf Dimension of the integer set), and $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}^1$, there is a natural definition of $\mathbb{R}^r$ with $0\leq r \leq 1$?

As I understand, any fractal over $\mathbb{R}$ with hausdorf dimension r would be a potential answer, but which one is the "natural" one?
Does Von Neumann's Continuous Geometry explain it, or is another field of math?

I make this question, because I want to understand what is $\mathbb{R}^r$, for example $\mathbb{R}^{0.5}$, and I do not know what I should study. Should I learn about Hyperspheres, Continuous Geometry, more about fractals?

Comment: Does $\mathbb{R}^r$ mean subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with Hausdorff dimension $r$?

Comment: Yes. Why is not clear?

Comment: It's just not a standard notation. Usually we use $\mathbb{R}^n$ to denote the $n$-dimensional real vector space; where $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @ AJY Oh, I used r to make clear that is not an integer.

Comment: But to your question, there are methods for constructing a $r$-dimensional set of $r$-dimensional Hausdorff measure $1$, but there's not really a "canonical" example in the sense of having a special relationship to the structure itself. Just standard and easy constructions.

Comment: @AJY I would like to know what are those methods. Maybe one of them has simpler properties (like simple addition and products), or something that makes it "natural".

Comment: Well probably the easiest is a modified Cantor set construction. The Cantor set was in many ways the "original" fractal, and it's easy enough to modify without really making it harder to work with. But if you're asking about fractals with nice *algebraic* properties, I know there's a chapter in Falconer's *Fractal Geometry: Mathematical Foundations and Applications* that discusses this. Really if you have any kind of interest in Hausdorff dimension, you should immediately go to your library and find Falconer. He is the standard reading for fractal geometry.

Comment: @AJY I'm on a public library, and I had just now got the book on my hands!. Do you mean the chapter 10 "Examples from number theory"? Well, thanks!. I have something to entertain me for a while.

Comment: Not chapter 10, no, though in my opinion it's a very interesting chapter no less. I was thinking of (some of) chapter 12.